# Migrating App Engine Backend services from java 7 runtime to java 8 runtime

Tags: java, google-app-engine, java-8, backend

I have a project that uses both frontend and backend instances, in java 7 runtime environment, using app engine (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/modules/converting)

We now want to migrate to java 8 runtime, however I can't find a way to migrate the backend module/services in this environment.
Because the EAR based structure is not supported in java 8 as mentioned in the first paragraph on the following link https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/configuration-files

Please help me with finding a way to achieve backend services/module in app engine java 8 runtime.

Any reference material or samples which can guide me to the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

The Cloud SDK-based plugin supports multiple services without requiring EAR packaging, and it is part of the process to migrate from Java7 to Java8, you will have to make some changes for Maven and the Gradle for Java8
For Maven, you will first need to [add the new plugin on your pom.xml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/migrate-maven#migrating_to_the_new_plugin), and second, [update your application.xml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/migrate-maven#migrating_ear-based_multi-service_configurations) if you were using an EAR based multi service configuration

For Gradle, you will add the new plugin to your classpath under dependencies in [your build.gradle](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/migrate-gradle#migrating_to_the_new_plugin) file, and you will also have to [update your run.services](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/migrate-gradle#migrating_ear_based_multi-service_configurations) file so that you can point to your default, secondary services.